# VBA Explicitly Request Variant Array As Opposed to String Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a combobox I am trying to populate using a range in an excel sheet. I extract the last row of the column, and then add all values in that range to the combo box. The issue is, if only one entry is there, Excel will extract just the single value as a string from the array, as opposed to a variant array.

This results in a type mismatch, because it is trying to assign the value as a string to a variant array. Is there a way to explicitly request a variant array as opposed to a the string value?

Here is the original code:

```
Dim hvVals() As Variant
lastRow = getLastRowInCol(Sheets("MySheet"), "B")
hvVals = Sheets("MySheet").Range("B2:B" & CStr(lastRow)).value
If Not isEmpty(hvVals) And lastRow <> 1 Then
Me.CECB.list = hvVals
```

Here is my attempt at a solution, but this does slow down my code a little and I don't know if it is very robust: (Also, the first row in the sheet is technically 2, which is why it's in the `if statement`)

```
Dim hvVals() As Variant
lastRow = getLastRowInCol(Sheets("MySheet"), "B")
If lastRow = 2 Then
    ReDim hvVals(1) As Variant
    hvVals(0) = Sheets("MySheet").Range(hvCol & "2:" & hvCol & CStr(lastRow)).value
Else
    hvVals = Sheets("MySheet").Range(hvCol & "2:" & hvCol & CStr(lastRow)).value
End If
If Not isEmpty(hvVals) And lastRow <> 1 Then
    Me.CECB.list = hvVals
```

Comment: When you pick up the Value of a (multi-cell) range you get a 2D variant array (1 to #rows, 1 to #columns): if you want to mimic that for a single cell you also need a 2D array (1 to 1, 1 to 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach

1. Take out the "()" from the variant declaration -if it's going to be an array your code logic should handle it-.

2. You don't need to convert to string the number in this line `Sheets("MySheet").Range("B2:B" & CStr(lastRow)).value`,I wouldn't risk it to cause a random error, change it for `Sheets("MySheet").Range("B2:B" & lastRow).value`

Prior "()"
[image]

After "()" was taken
[image]

3. My advise -if you really need it variable- would be to check for the Ubound of the variable and, if it's greater than 0, it means more than one value was found and do your handling accordingly.

4.Why not to make an array of ranges instead? You can play easier with that since you can get the ".value" property that way.

Comment: Trying 1 seems to work. I also think I will try 4 if I run into any more issues. I think I originally chose a variant because I wasn't sure if `combobox.list` would handle taking in a `range.value` type. But I do normally work with ranges. Thanks for the help!